# Why Google Maps can not be displayed?

Tags: android, json, maps, android-manifest, google-maps-android-api-2

I had a problem like this in logcat :

```
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     ... 11 more
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ck.a(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.i.a(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ab.a(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.aa.a(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

I want to show google maps by utilizing Google APIs, but that happens application stop by itself, this is my MainActictivity

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment
        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Creating GoogleMap from SupportMapFragment
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation button for the Google Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Setting OnClickEvent listener for the GoogleMap
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {
                addMarker(latlng);
                sendToServer(latlng);
            }
        });

        // Starting locations retrieve task
        new RetrieveTask().execute();

    }

    // Adding marker on the GoogleMaps
    private void addMarker(LatLng latlng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
        markerOptions.title(latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    // Invoking background thread to store the touched location in Remove MySQL server
    private void sendToServer(LatLng latlng) {
        new SaveTask().execute(latlng);
    }


    // Background thread to save the location in remove MySQL server
    private class SaveTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
            String lat = Double.toString(params[0].latitude);
            String lng = Double.toString(params[0].longitude);
            String strUrl = "http://192.168.191.1/location_marker_mysql/save.php";                  
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        connection.getOutputStream());

                outputStreamWriter.write("lat=" + lat + "&lng="+lng);               
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
                outputStreamWriter.close();

                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";

                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    // Background task to retrieve locations from remote mysql server
    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strUrl = "http://192.168.191.1/location_marker_mysql/retrieve.php";              
            URL url = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();              
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));         
                String line = "";               
                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();                            

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }

    }

    // Background thread to parse the JSON data retrieved from MySQL server
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>>{
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = markerParser.parse(json);
            return markersList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> marker = result.get(i);
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng")));
                addMarker(latlng);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am using MySQL database to store the dang latitude longtitude to be a marker will be displayed in the maps, but still can not because there is an error. Is there something wrong with my Manifest? Here's my manifest

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!-- Protect the map component of the application using application signature -->
    <permission 
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!--  Allows to receive map -->
    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Used by the Google Maps Android API V2 to download map tiles from Google Maps servers -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use WiFi or mobile cell data (or both) to determine the device's location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use the Global Positioning System (GPS) 
    to determine the device's location to within a very small area -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Allows to contact Google Serves -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

     <!-- Google Maps Android API V2 requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Specifies the Android API Key, which is obtained from Google API Console -->
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDDoOiE8El5PyA3HQn2uu1qA90vcm3htQo" /> 
         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Maybe my friends can help me, I am new in the world of Android, please explanation, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you encounter error check your logcat and in that check caused by  as from your logcat : Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
01-27 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938):

Just add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` into your manifest file.

Comment: Thanks youuu so much, now application running, but maps can't load in my apps, what happen? @user2455320

Answer (score 2):

Your logcat clearly said

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the
 additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml
 to ensure a correct behavior: 01-27 18:27:12.403:
 AndroidRuntime(3938): <uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 01-27
 18:27:12.403: E/AndroidRuntime(3938)
```

add in your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This permission allows the `API` to check the **network connection** status in order to determine whether data can be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks youuu so much, now application running, but maps can't load in my apps, what happen? @M D

Comment: @M D yes succeeded thanks, to change the map in the form of street how ?? because I show you a map of the world